# VB.NET - Error with Spell Checker (NHunspell)

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, hunspell

Basically I'm using [NHunspell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56332/NHunspellTextBoxExtender-A-Spellchecking-IExtender) to check for spelling errors and I've come across an error and problem.

The Error is that whenever the NHunspell is added to a textbox or richtextbox, it simply cannot be docked to a container or resized while docked. It crashes. In order to avoid this error I have to simply lock the form and disable the maximize button. This way the user can just close and resize the program.

The error:

```
`System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at NHunspellExtender.NHunspellTextBoxExtender.CustomPaintTextBox.TextBoxBase_ClientSizeChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)`
```

The other problem is that there seems to be performance issues. If i was to load a file with about 500+ characters and there are quite a bit of errors let's say 25, and I try to scroll down the page, it get's quite laggy.

I know this is a lot but I'm wondering if anyone who has been using this found a solution to it of if anyone can help me that would be great!

PS. The problem ONLY happens if i'm using RichTextBoxes. TextBoxes are fine.

Comment: This is primary a problem of the NHunspellTextBoxExtender you use and not of NHunspell.

Comment: @ThomasMaierhofer So there is a problem in the way the user had created the NHunspellTextBoxExtender? Is there a work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

An easier workaround was to use the WPF RichTextBox. This came with a default Spell Check which Now I'm using in WinForms. I did this by Using the Host Element for WinForms. Although the [TUTORIAL](http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) uses a DataGrid it's easy to change it to whatever control you want.

However I would still like to know a solution.